# GeoWebCache format modifiers

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, getmap

I'm trying to implement format modifiers within my geowebcache.
My understanding is such that I can specify the format sent in the getmap request, and have GeoWebCache convert it to my desired format. This process is outlined [here](https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/caching_data/diskquotas.html).

I've tried applying the format modifier as described in the above link:

```
"formatModifiers": [
  {
    "requestFormat": "image/tiff",
    "responseFormat": "image/png"
  }
]
```

However, when I seed the layer and monitor the getmap requests they are bypassing this filter and
being requested as PNG.

I'm currently running GeoServer 2.22.0 and GeoWebCache 1.22.0. Is this feature no longer supported, am I misunderstanding its use, or am I configuring it incorrectly?

Example of a WMS layer:

```
    <wmsLayer>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <name>workspace:layer</name>
  <mimeFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
  </mimeFormats>
  <formatModifiers>
    <formatModifier>
      <responseFormat>image/png</responseFormat>
      <requestFormat>image/tiff</requestFormat>
    </formatModifier>
  </formatModifiers>
  <gridSubsets>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:3857</gridSetName>
      <extent>
        <coords>
          <double>xxxxxxx</double>
          <double>xxxxxxx</double>
          <double>xxxxxxx</double>
          <double>xxxxxxx</double>
        </coords>
      </extent>
      <zoomStart>0</zoomStart>
      <zoomStop>10</zoomStop>
      <minCachedLevel>0</minCachedLevel>
      <maxCachedLevel>10</maxCachedLevel>
    </gridSubset>
  </gridSubsets>
  <metaWidthHeight>
    <int>3</int>
    <int>3</int>
  </metaWidthHeight>
  <expireCacheList>
    <expirationRule minZoom="0" expiration="-2"/>
  </expireCacheList>
  <expireClientsList>
    <expirationRule minZoom="0" expiration="-2"/>
  </expireClientsList>
  <backendTimeout>60</backendTimeout>
  <cacheBypassAllowed>false</cacheBypassAllowed>
  <queryable>false</queryable>
  <parameterFilters>
    <stringParameterFilter>
      <key>STYLES</key>
      <defaultValue>generic</defaultValue>
      <values>
        <string>workspace:style</string>
      </values>
    </stringParameterFilter>
  </parameterFilters>
  <wmsUrl>
    <string>http://localhost/geoserver/wms?</string>
  </wmsUrl>
  <wmsLayers>workspace:layer</wmsLayers>
  <gutter>0</gutter>
  <wmsVersion>1.1.1</wmsVersion>
  <transparent>true</transparent>
  <palette>safe</palette>
  <concurrency>32</concurrency>
</wmsLayer>
```

- I've also tried applying the format modifiers at the global scope such that it applies to every layer.

Comment: Have you if the order of the parameters matters by writing the responseFormat before requestFormat as in the examples in https://www.geosolutionsgroup.com/blog/tips-tricks-geowebcache-tweaks-checklist/?

Comment: The layer defined within geowebcache.xml specifies the responseFormat before the requestFormat as shown in my WMS layer example. The JSON representation is what I used in my PUT request when creating the layer.